# What are the factors that decide where to use what motor?

Tags: dc-motor, induction-motor

What is the basic difference between single phase motors, three-phase motors, brake motors, synchronous motors, asynchronous motors, Induction Motors, etc.?

What are the factors that decide where to use which motor?

Comment: I wouldn't say this is a simple question - there are entire books written on motor types and theory. It would probably help if you narrowed your question a bit; to one or two points that you need help with, or one or two motors. I imagine you will get better answers this way.

Comment: It sounds like you just need to read up about motors in general, then come back with any specific questions. [Electric motors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_motor); [Brushless DC motors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brushless_DC_electric_motor)

Comment: I would highly recommend reading a book on electrical machines and drives. This is very well-known 'old' technology, so with a bit of googling you should be able to find cheap or free (e)books on the subject matter. There is no single answer, and for many applications many different types of motors would spec-wise fit, so the decision is usually down to either very specific technical reasons, cost and reliability.

Comment: @user26129: This is fair, but could you perhaps recommend something without gazillions of charts and equations?

Comment: @Oli Come on Guys.. Instead you can just answer me listing basic difference between these.Anyway I know this is very basic question but trust me I am always confuse. So I respect the person who share sthe knowledge without considering the question weight. Please guys help me

Comment: @Yogus sometimes, there is no "royal road".  So, be morally prepared to sift through a lot of technical material.  At the same time, I've voted *not* to close this question as *too broad*.

Comment: @NickAlexeev Thanks . Can you please share any webpage which list the difference between these in their behaviours. I have searched google but I can only find the big articles, ebooks, webpages,dicussions but not quick small reference . I am in need to small quick reference kind material. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Yogus , As you can see from my quick answer it's a broad subject that needs consideration in lots of ways, however what you sometimes find is that the motor you use depends on what you have or know about. For example I read somewhere (I can't find the link at the moment) the controler in first Tesla car determined the type of motor used.

Comment: This question, as it stands, applies to AC motors but doesn't cover the full range of possibilities of all conventional AC motors. Even if this site was geared up to answering a question about the pros and cons of all AC motors, the question falls short because it only mentions a subset of ac motors with no justification as to why it is a subset. It also mentions brake motors and this is "any" motor type with a "brake" i.e. it is irrelevant. Here's a link to wiki that might help http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AC_motor just to prove I can help as well as vote to close.

Comment: @Yogus  You didn't seem to get my point.  Do you know what the expression "no royal road" means and where it came from?

Answer (score 2):

Some of the factors used to determine the motor to be used.

- How much torque is needed? Is a gearbox needed?
- How much space is the motor and controller allowed?
- How much does it cost?
- How easy is it to obtain?
- How is it connected to the load?
- What type of load is it? (stiff or lose coupled?)
- What are the EMI considerations needed for the application?
- How much cooling is required?
- Does it ever need maintenance? (for example brushes  that need changing)

Comment: Thanks. I will these points otherwise. These ars the points which differ motors. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

There is no right answer.  Typically the decision is made based on the supply type, torque, RPM, size.  Then if you have special needs like low-slip, etc.  Spoon posted in the middle of my typing this up, so I'll stop there as his list is as good as any.

I suggest you invert the question and examine your application's restrictions then narrow the pool of motors that would work and come back with a more specific question regarding those types.